# Scipy expect function not giving expected output

Tags: python, scipy

When using the expect function for an exponentially distributed random variable, I can't get the intended output. Here is a small example, where I take the expectation over the function "x = 1" over the range 0 to 3. This is equivalent to integrating the density function, so the output should equal the CDF evaluated in 3.

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import expon

mu = 0.3
rv = expon(scale=1/mu)
upper = 3.

print rv.dist.expect(lambda x: 1.,lb = 0.,ub = upper)
```

Which returns 0.950212931632.

The cdf of the exponential distribution evaluated in upper should give the same result:

```
print rv.cdf(upper)
```

But this gives 0.593430340259.

This may not be the most insightful question, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone see the mistake? Or is there some mistake in the expect function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
rv = expon(scale=1/mu)
```

creates a "frozen" distribution with the scale fixed at 1/mu.
A frozen distribution is an instance of the `rv_frozen` class.
This class hold a reference to an *unfrozen* distribution in its
`dist` attribute.  Because `dist` is not a frozen distribution,
if you use any methods in `dist`, you must give all the arguments
(otherwise they use the same defaults as `expon`, and not the
frozen arguments).

```
In [57]: mu = 0.3

In [58]: rv = expon(scale=1/mu)

In [59]: upper = 3.0

In [60]: rv.dist.expect(func=lambda x: 1, scale=1/mu, lb=0, ub=upper)
Out[60]: 0.5934303402594009

In [61]: rv.cdf(upper)
Out[61]: 0.59343034025940089
```

Instead of using the `dist` attribute, you could just as easily
use the `expon.expect` method:

```
In [62]: expon.expect(func=lambda x: 1, scale=1/mu, lb=0, ub=upper)
Out[62]: 0.5934303402594009
```

The "real" problem here is that the frozen distribution doesn't
provide the `expect` method.  If it seems like an important feature
to have, you could create an issue with an enhancement request on
the [scipy github site](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues).

Comment: Thanks.I noticed that rv.expect does not exist, so I figured I'd use rv.dist.expect instead without knowing it required the scale parameter again. My bad.